# Google Directions API billing

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-platform, google-directions-api

I am implementing an Android app and I want to use the Directions API but I get this error when I try the HTTP GET Request:

```
{
   "error_message" : "You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I know I have to enable billing, what I want to know is the limits. I am doing this app for student purposes so this app won't be used by any users but me. I wanna know If it's safe to put my credit card if there is a limit that you can use it for free. I know there is a free trial but after that any request, even one will cost me money??
Thank you.

Comment: For questions such as these, it is best if you file a support ticket to them directly here: https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support. They will be able to address all your concerns regarding billing, pricing, free trial and setting limits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the free GCP tier, the free trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 3 months, whichever happens first.

At that time, the following conditions apply:

- You must upgrade to a paid account to continue using Google Cloud.
- All resources you created during the trial are stopped.
- Any data you stored in Compute Engine is lost.

Your account enters a 30-day grace period, during which you can recover resources and data you stored in any Google Cloud services during the trial period.

You might receive a message stating that your account has been canceled, which only indicates that your account has been suspended to prevent charges.

If you want to manage your expenses you may set up budget alerts https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#create-budget also you can set up capping usage for it https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage